# How to use oauth2client.tools.run_flow with exceptions in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, google-drive-api, oauth2client

When I try to run the below code,

```
from oauth2client import tools
creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
```

When I close the web browser without logging into it, Following is the screen that appears and freeze like this way on terminal and the page keeps loading and show nothing in my django web page.

[image]

Is their anyway I can use exception for this ? like if the user doesn't login then it won't start the process.?

[reference](https://readthedocs.org/projects/oauth2client/downloads/pdf/latest/)

Please find below my whole code,

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import argparse


class Drive:
    # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            flags = tools.argparser.parse_args([])
        except ImportError:
            flags = None

        store = file.Storage('token.json')
        self.creds = store.get()
        if not self.creds or self.creds.invalid:
            flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON, self.SCOPES)
            try:
                if flags:
                    self.creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
                    print("self.creds",self.creds)
            except:
                pass
        self.service = build('drive', 'v3', http=self.creds.authorize(Http()))
```

Comment: If you can share the whole code that you have worked on, it will be more helpful to address your concern.

Comment: @Twilight Please check now. I have added my whole code in the question.